# What is the simplest way to move this div to the left?

Tags: html, css

I am unsure of how to proceed. I have 3 div tags layed out like so (well this is a simplified version anyways):

```
<div class="gray" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100px;overflow:auto;">
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to move orange to the left of gray using css so that I do not have to change the html but I am stuck on how to do it properly. Here is a picture (I would like to move orange to green):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqPuI.png

Comment: Who's voting to close a CSS question as off-topic? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/ `::scowl::`

Comment: Sighh, I remember the days when I could logon to SO and ask a question about html, css, (as well as c#, sql) and get my answers from one great place... please don't let anal tards ruin it for us...

Comment: @Matt, I closed as belongs on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), which that question doesn't even mention.  @Dal, Stack Overflow has always been primarily about programming.  That's why they created Webmasters.

Comment: @Matthew: not interested in fighting you on that (it's a moot point) but that meta question was posted long before webmasters.se existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do it using absolute positioning:

```
.orange{
position: absolute;
left: -200px; /* or whatever distance you want */
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it causes orange to get clipped like this: http://imgur.com/CAOkw.png

Comment: Its because I am using "overflow:auto;" on gray

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm not sure it's possible doing this any other way.  You may have to change the styles on other elements in the page to keep it from cutting off.  I would play with different styles in FireBug.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a negative margin:

http://jsfiddle.net/wkKDy/1/

Answer (score 1):

using position-relative would do it

```
.orange{ position: relative; left: -200px }
```

if it still gets clipped, make sure the parent element doesn't have overflow: hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/wkKDy/4/

- edit - oh, you got it. nice.